# Abstract methods not showing up as covered in coverage report

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I have an abstract class containing a abstract method

```
abstract class AbstractImporter
{
    abstract protected function runImporter();
}
```

An implementation class

```
SomeImporter extends AbstractImporter
{
    public function runImporter()
    {
        //This does some work
    }
}
```

And a unit test

```
SomeImporterTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testRunImporter()
    {
        $importer = new SomeImporter();
        $importer->runImporter();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

If I run this the line containing the abstract method definition in `AbstractImporter` is showing up as not covered.

I have also tried adding the `@covers AbstractImporter::runImporter` annotation in `SomeImporter`.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Edit:

It **does** show as **unreachable** when I create a report using `--coverage-html`, but my IDE (PHPStorm) is showing the line as **uncovered**. PHPStorm is using `--coverage-clover` and in the clover xml I see the following line:

```
<line num="66" type="method" name="runImporter" crap="1" count="0"/>
```

Comment: does it lower your coverage? my phpunit shows it as unreachable (white) code, not as uncovered (red) code.

Comment: yup I have 98% in my library and it should be 100% ;)

Comment: I'll check in clover html report. My phpstorm shows it as uncovered

Comment: @cweiske, In html reports the line is unreachable as you said and I reach 100%. It is eighter a bug in PHP Storm of the clover xml export it is using. I see the following line in the XML `<line num="66" type="method" name="runImporter" crap="1" count="0"/>`. Is this correct?

Comment: The XML line is in the AbstractImporter so I think it's a bug in the xml. I'm not sure about the meaning of the `crap` attribute.